# Is it possible to read sub URL as query string in PHP?

Tags: php, query-string

## This is my LOCAL URL:

http://localhost/wbdrupal/?url=http://werkbad-konfigurator.de/datahub/searchObjectByID?table=furniture&column=wbid&search=

when I echo this variable `$_GET['url'];`

then the output is http://werkbad-konfigurator.de/datahub/searchObjectByID?table=furniture

but I need output as http://werkbad-konfigurator.de/datahub/searchObjectByID?table=furniture&column=wbid&search=

I need full query string when I write this command: `echo $_GET['url'];`

Comment: url_encode your url variable before you put it into the string.

Comment: $i_need_output = $_GET['url'].'&'.$_GET['search'];

Comment: best way you can base64_encode your url and pass it in "GET" you will get url as string and then you can base64_decode($GET['url])

Answer (score 3):

Your URL is malformed and can't be parsed.  The system has no way of knowing which key/value pairs belong to the actual URL or to the `url` *value* you're trying to submit.

You need to URL-encode your values so the system can know what the key/value pairs are:

```
http://localhost/wbdrupal/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwerkbad-konfigurator.de%2Fdatahub%2FsearchObjectByID%3Ftable%3Dfurniture%26column%3Dwbid%26search%3D
```